# Magnetic ballast with g23 bulb with capacitor

Tags: voltage, light, lighting, uv, ballast

I am trying to make a UV-b photo-therapy light and want to make sure I'm understanding the circuitry correctly-so i don't hastily burn a $50 bulb. 
Im using a Phillips PL-S 9W/01/2P (link [here](https://www.assets.lighting.philips.com/is/content/PhilipsLighting/fp927901700121-pss-global)). It's a 9 watt 2 pin g23 socket bulb.

From what I've found, I need a 9w magnetic ballast, as electronic ballasts won't work with the build in preheat capacitor in the bulb. The part that I'm confucius about is the voltage that the bulb receives. The spec sheet  says 60V, but am confused about how to match that part up with a correct ballast. I tried to track down a good example and have [this](https://www.lightbulbsurplus.com/keystone-technologies-cc579tp.html).
Any suggestions for the correct ballast or any other circutry 'magic' I haven't taken into account?

Thanks

Comment: looks similar to these http://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/lighting-electronics/fluorescent/fluorescent-electromagnetic/bpl-em-ballasts-for-cfl-pl-t-pl-s-and-pl-c-lamps/913710122350_EU/product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[Philips](http://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/lighting-electronics/fluorescent/fluorescent-electromagnetic/bpl-em-ballasts-for-cfl-pl-t-pl-s-and-pl-c-lamps/913710122350_EU/product) have a similar Ballast with a switch (S) wire as follows.